# How to calculate the position of objects in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I am new to 3D Graphics programming. I'm using Three.js to design a software that uses 3D visualisation for 3D bin packaging. Right now I'm using the below code to create and position two elements.

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var mesh, mesh2;
init();
function init() {
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
  camera.position.z = 800;
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/crate.gif' );
  var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
  var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {map:texture} );
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material );
  mesh2.position.x = 170
  mesh2.position.y = -48
  mesh2.position.z = 100
  mesh.rotation.x = 0.45;
  mesh.rotation.y = 1;
  mesh2.rotation.x = 0.45;
  mesh2.rotation.y = 1;
  scene.add( mesh2 );
  scene.add( mesh );
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
}
```

Right now I'm using (170, -48, 100) as the coordinates to align the second cube. I've arrived to these numbers by tweaking the numbers and constantly checking. But there should be some formula to get these x,y,z since I'm rotating them to a certain angle (x=0.45, y=1). I'm not sure how to start the calculation for this.

The problem statement is, given a set of cubes dimensions' (l1, w1, h1), (h2, w2, h2) and so on and cubes positions (x1, y1, z1) (x2, y2, z2) how to calculate and place them near and/or stack them?

Comment: you need to be more specific as `near` is different than `stack`

Comment: My apologies, by near I wanted to mention next to without any gap (as shown in the example). Since I want it to be close by any axis x, y, z I just mentioned 'near'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make mesh2 a child of mesh: `mesh.add( mesh2 )`

`mesh2` will inherit rotation of `mesh` and you will define relative offsets to shift it in coordinate space of parent.

Fixed example:

```
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material );
  mesh2.position.x = 170
  //mesh2.position.y = -48
  //mesh2.position.z = 100
  mesh.rotation.x = 0.45;
  mesh.rotation.y = 1;
  //mesh2.rotation.x = 0.45;
  //mesh2.rotation.y = 1;
  scene.add( mesh );
  mesh.add( mesh2 ); // << ---- solution
```

**Updated:** Also possible without parent-child hierarchy.

```
  let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  let mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material );
  //  mesh2.position.x = 170
  //  mesh2.position.y = -48
  //  mesh2.position.z = 100
  mesh.rotation.x = 0.45;
  mesh.rotation.y = 1;
  mesh.updateMatrix(); // <<-- this is essential, to write .position and .rotation values into object transformation matrix.

  // mesh2.rotation.x = 0.45;
  // mesh2.rotation.y = 1;
  scene.add( mesh );

  // apply local transforms
  mesh2.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(210, 0, 0));

  // apply transforms of mesh on top
  mesh2.applyMatrix(mesh.matrix);

  scene.add( mesh2 ); // << ---- add directly to Scene
```

Comment: Yes! This works. So whenever I want to add an element relative to another element it should be it's child? So this will become a tree like structure right? Is there an alternate approach? Maybe a mathematical one?

Comment: Since no one added a mathematical answer, I accept this as the answer